# Google Prediction Training Error Message

Tags: google-api, prediction, google-prediction

I'm trying to train a model to use in the `Google Prediction API`. I uploaded a csv with ~1 million rows and ~10 columns ~12 hours ago. The `trainingStatus` has been "RUNNING" every time I've checked it over the past few hours but when I make a `prediction.trainedmodels.get` request using the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/prediction/v1.6/prediction.trainedmodels.get) it returns this response:

```
{
 "kind": "prediction#training",
 "id": "my_model",
 "selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/prediction/v1.6/projects/my_project/trainedmodels/my_model",
 "created": "2014-03-24T03:36:51.252Z",
 "trainingStatus": "ERROR"
}
```

Is there any way to get a <strike>more</strike> detailed error message?

I have a valid billing profile enabled on my project and I don't see anything in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/prediction/docs/reference/v1.6/trainedmodels/get).

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/prediction/docs/faq

> **I get the message "ERROR" after training on my training file. What
>   happened?**
>
> While we constantly strive to offer more detailed error
>   messages, this message is currently being returned if training failed,
>   the prediction engine can't find the training file, or for other
>   errors. If you keep getting this message, check your training query to
>   be sure that the path to your data is correct, and check your training
>   data format to ensure that you do not have extra newline characters or
>   commas, then try resubmitting your training request.